# Alternative image (via IF function) isn't working

Tags: php, image, http

i am trying to get a Minecraft player's skin via PHP, and it all works, until the user enteres an invalid username, techniclly, if that happenes the script should replace the not found image with an alternative image, but for some reason it doesn't. 
full script:

```
<?php
//initial settings
header("Content-type: image/png");

//declere values
$name = $_GET['n'];

//get the image from Minecraft main servers
$src = imagecreatefrompng("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/{$name}.png");
//if not found, use an alternative image
if(!$src){
$src = imagecreatefrompng("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/char.png");
}

//display the skin
imagepng($src);
?>
```

Any help will be appriciated, thank you.

Comment: you should check if that png exists ( `file_exists()` ) and not if `!$src` ... I am pretty sure that the resource returned by imagecreatefrompng is always true

Comment: @Najzero, According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php, `imagecreatefrompng` "Returns an image resource identifier on success, FALSE on errors."

Comment: @Jordan Hey I tried to run your exact code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
//initial settings
header("Content-type: image/png");

//declere values
$name = $_GET['n'];

//get the image from Minecraft main servers
if(file_exists("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/{$name}.png")) {
   $src = imagecreatefrompng("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/{$name}.png");
//if not found, use an alternative image
else {
   $src = imagecreatefrompng("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/char.png");
}

//display the skin
imagepng($src);
?>
```

Comment: Nope, it just displays the alternative image, even if the name entered is valid.